# The name 'ASPQueryStringEncryption' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

```
<a href='ProductDetails.aspx?id=<%# ASPQueryStringEncryption.MyCrypto.GetEncryptedQueryString(Eval("ProductID").ToString()) %>'>View Details</a>
```

I'am using `ASPQueryStringEncryption` but he tell me:

> The name 'ASPQueryStringEncryption' does not exist in the current
>   context

Comment: What is the `ASPQueryStringEncryption`?

Comment: @SelimYıldız Incrypte the Url

Comment: You need to import namespace with `ASPQueryStringEncryption` into your code behind file

Comment: @RomanMarusyk Yes Ido

Comment: Then why not show us? Should we guess? Do you have something like `<%@ Page Language="C#" CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs" .. %>` in aspx file?

Comment: @RomanMarusyk <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/_MainLayout.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ProjectsList.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.ProjectsList" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>

Comment: @RomanMarusyk using System.Security.Cryptography;

Comment: no, it isn't. `MyCrypto` should be your class and `ASPQueryStringEncryption` should be your main namesapce for project. Show us namespace in `Login.aspx.cs` file

Comment: @RomanMarusyk ok bro it's working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you're following to this article [How to encrypt query string in ASP.NET.](http://www.dotnetawesome.com/2013/10/how-to-encrypt-query-string-in-aspnet.html). In that case the `ASPQueryStringEncryption` is application(project) name.

The `MyCrypto` is should be your class, so check the namespace of it and use instead of `ASPQueryStringEncryption`

```
<a href='ProductDetails.aspx?id=<%# APPLICATION_NAMESPACE.MyCrypto.GetEncryptedQueryString(Eval("ProductID").ToString()) %>'>View Details</a>
```

In most cases it should start with your project name